# Convert GPIO_TypeDef from STM32L1xx to STM32F10x

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I have the following code which includes `STM32L1xx.h`:

```
 GPIO_TypeDef* gpioport ... // Declaration.

 gpioport->MODER   = (gpioport->MODER   & ~(3 << pin2)) | (((gpiocfg >> GPIOCFG_MODE_SHIFT  ) & 3) << pin2);
 gpioport->OSPEEDR = (gpioport->OSPEEDR & ~(3 << pin2)) | (((gpiocfg >> GPIOCFG_OSPEED_SHIFT) & 3) << pin2);
 gpioport->OTYPER  = (gpioport->OTYPER  & ~(1 << pin )) | (((gpiocfg >> GPIOCFG_OTYPE_SHIFT ) & 1) << pin );
 gpioport->PUPDR   = (gpioport->PUPDR   & ~(3 << pin2)) | (((gpiocfg >> GPIOCFG_PUPD_SHIFT  ) & 3) << pin2);
```

I want to replace the `STM32L1xx.h` with `STM32F10x.h`, but `MODER`, `OSPEEDR`, `OTYPER` and `PUPDR` are not defined in the `GPIO_TypeDef` struct in `STM32F10x.h`. I didn't find a similar struct in `STM32F10x.h`, neither.

Is it possible to convert the above code? If so which struct in STM32F10x.h should I use?

Comment: These are headers targeting different families of microcontrollers, the GPIO peripherals for which are largely equivalent but offer slightly different feature sets and interfaces. In other words you _cannot_ mechanically port code from one to the other and will need to read the reference manuals to understand the underlying interfaces. A suitable hardware abstraction library can help in writing common code for both devices but won't relieve you from understanding device to be ported _from_ or from learning the hardware involved and its limitations.

Comment: @doynax: If you refer to that bloatware STlib/HAL: this is of no practical use. Better write drivers using the registers directly. This also encapsulates the hardwar, but does not require a useless intermediate layer.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the two mcus, these two have different gpio peripherals.  Similar features the registers are just setup differently so you will need to port the code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in stm32f10x_gpio.h. This has a structure `GPIO_InitTypeDef` and the relevant defines for setting it up. It should be simple to translate what you currently have to what you need for the STM32F1.

I don't have the current STM32F1 Cube stuff downloaded, so I think possibly the file may now be called stm32f1xx_hal_gpio.h (or similar), but I think the typedef will still be called `GPIO_InitTypeDef`.

The STM libraries are a bit bloated, but if you just take what you need I find they are very useful. In particular the processor headers and the #defines.